# AudioKit AKPlayer can not loopback to beginning with setPosition

Tags: ios, audiokit

In v4, If you use `AKPlayer` with looping and use `setPosition` API, the player loops between the position set with `setPosition` and the players total duration. What I needed was to start from the position set by `setPosition` API and loop to the beginning when looping occurs. I am not sure if this is intentional or not but I need to be able to seek to a certain point in the Player and loop to the beginning and for now it seems that this is not a feature in AudioKit.
Is there a way or workaround to achieve this? I need to accomplish this as a requirement.
To reproduce here is an full playground example:

```
import AudioKitPlaygrounds
import AudioKit

let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "3.aac")

//: Set up a player to the loop the file's playback
var player = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
player.isLooping = true
player.buffering = .always

AKManager.output = player
try AKManager.start()


player.setPosition(player.duration - 2)
player.play(at: AVAudioTime.now())
// player loops between player.duration - 2, player.duration  forever. I want it to loop between 0, player.duration

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Expected behavior
I expected it to loop back to the beginning.

Details:

- AudioKit Version 4.11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to develop some kind of looper application, I think the approach is to use a sequencer to coordinate the playback of your audio files. At each position where a sound should start playing, you add an event to the sequence.

The sequencer can be connected to a callback instrument, which is a node that passes the events to an user-defined function. In your callback function, you would start playback of the audio file indicated by that event.

This is an outline of what should be done:

1. Create a track to contain the playback events, using [AKSequencer](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSequencer.html)'s [addTrack](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSequencer.html#/s:8AudioKit11AKSequencerC8addTrack3forAA0cE0CAA6AKNodeC_tF) method. Connect this track to an [AKCallbackInstrument](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKCallbackInstrument.html). Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545391/2679386) on how to connect an AKCallbackInstrument to an AKSequencer track. Set the sequencer's and the track's `length` to the total duration of the song (notice these properties are represented in beats instead of seconds). Set the sequencer's `loopEnabled` as desired.
2. Add the playback events to the track, at the time positions where you want each sound to play. As you will be interpreting the events yourself with a callback function, it doesn't really matter what type of event you use. You could simply use a `Note On`.
3. In the callback function, start playing the corresponding sound when that event is received.

You would need a couple of classes to represent some basic information about where each sample occurs in the song:

```
class Beat {
    var sample: Sample!
    var onsetTime: Double

    var endTime {
        get {
            return onsetTime + sample.duration
        }
    }
}

class Sample {
    var url: URL!
    var duration: Double
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var samples: [Sample] = []
    var beats: [Beat] = []

    var player: AKPlayer!
    var sequencer: AKSequencer!
}
```

On the note’s pitch you would store the index of the sample you want to play. This is what your callback function would look like:

```
func playCallback(status:UInt8, note:MIDINoteNumber, vel:MIDIVelocity) -> () {
    guard let status = AKMIDIStatus(byte: status),
        let type = status.type,
        type == .noteOn else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        player.load(samples[note].url)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

You can use `AKSequencer`’s `seek` method to start playing your song at some arbitrary position.

There is a special case where the sequencer starts to play in the middle of a beat. In that case, you must manually start the playback of that sample.

```
func play(at time: Double = 0) {
    sequencer.seek(time)
    sequencer.play()
    for beat in beats {
        if beat.onsetTime < time && time < beat.endTime {
            player.load(beat.sample.url)
            player.play(from: time - beat.onsetTime)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is AKPlayer still available? Looks like it was removed from AudioKit.

Comment: AKPlayer was removed, there are now three nodes that you can use for playing back audio files: AppleSampler, AudioPlayer, and MultiSegmentAudioPlayer

Comment: Thx! I am new to audio. I want to add an equalizer to Apple's AVPlayer playing HLS video streaming. I did lots of research but have not found any viable solution yet. Some works with streaming .mp3 but not .m3u8. Not sure if you can give any advice.

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255720/chat-with-rao)